# Qgis - taudem plugin - python script not found

Tags: python, sextante-qgis-plugin

I installed the sextante toolbox on qgis.
my os is fedora.

grass works fine but i've got problems with taudem. it seems like some python files are missing. 
for instance when i try to run the pitremove algorithm the sextante info log yields: 
"HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file /home/me/.qgis/python/plugins/sextante/taudem/pitremove (No such file or directory)"

indeed, there's no pitremove.py in the plugins/sextante/taudem directory.

so did I missed one step in the plugin installation ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the installation instructinos in the QGIS manual, in the SEXTANTE chapter?

I do not know which versino you are using, but I'd recommend using QGIS master, which has the latest SEXTANTE. There have been several bugfixes, and as far as I remember, some affected the TauDEM interface.

Hope this helps

Comment: it did helped 
i was missing a step in the taudem installation process
now i am struggling with the make instruction.
thanks !